# IP address starting FROM a maxAddress

Tags: go

I've a need where I need to start generating IP addresses
given a CIDR and some cached address.
I've some code here where I'm doing bytes.Compare with stored
address and only select those that are greater.

https://play.golang.org/p/yT_Mj4fR_jK

What is going wrong here? Basically I need all the addresses
from "62.76.47.9" in "62.76.47.12/28". Generating the IPs
in the given CIDR range is wellknown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you print `ìpMax`, you'll see its underlying representation is using 16 bytes. (see also the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP)

```
fmt.Printf("'%#v'\n",ipMax)

'net.IP{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xff, 0x3e, 0x4c, 0x2f, 0x9}'
```

You can convert `ipMax` to an IPv4 representation to have your desired results:

```
ipMax := net.ParseIP("62.76.47.9").To4()
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will print addresses starting from the first address of 62.76.47.12/28 up to 62.76.47.9.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/MUtbiKaQ_3-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    cidr := "62.76.47.12/28"
    _, ipnet, _ := net.ParseCIDR(cidr)
    ipFirst := ipnet.IP
    ipFirstValue := toHost(ipFirst)

    ipLast := net.ParseIP("62.76.47.9")
    ipLastValue := toHost(ipLast)

    fmt.Println("cidr:  ", cidr)
    fmt.Println("first: ", ipFirst)
    fmt.Println("last:  ", ipLast)

    if ipLastValue < ipFirstValue {
        fmt.Println("ugh")
        return
    }

    for i := ipFirstValue; i < ipLastValue; i++ {
        addr := toIP(i)
        fmt.Println(addr)
    }
}

func toHost(ip net.IP) uint32 {
    i := ip.To4()
    return uint32(i[0])<<24 + uint32(i[1])<<16 + uint32(i[2])<<8 + uint32(i[3])
}

func toIP(v uint32) net.IP {
    v3 := byte(v & 0xFF)
    v2 := byte((v >> 8) & 0xFF)
    v1 := byte((v >> 16) & 0xFF)
    v0 := byte((v >> 24) & 0xFF)
    return net.IPv4(v0, v1, v2, v3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/), I can provide two ways of doing this, one way that is similar to your proposal by iterating the whole subnet, as well as another that starts from the given address and increments until it reaches the max address. Note that these solutions work identically with IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

Note that the enclosing CIDR subnet for `62.76.47.12/28` and `62.76.47.9/28` is `62.76.47.0/28`, so you really do not need to supply both `62.76.47.12/28` and `62.76.47.9`, you could simply supply the single string `62.76.47.9/28`.  But for the sake of adhering to your proposed example, I will work with both strings.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    cidrString, addrString := "62.76.47.12/28", "62.76.47.9"
    addr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(addrString).GetAddress()
    cidrAddr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(cidrString).GetAddress()
    iterateThroughSubnet(addr, cidrAddr) // solution 1
    incrementAddressToMax(addr, cidrAddr) // solution 2
}

func iterateThroughSubnet(addr, cidrAddr *ipaddr.IPAddress) {
    block := cidrAddr.ToPrefixBlock().WithoutPrefixLen()
    fmt.Printf("\nstarting with block %s, equivalent to %v,\nand address %s\n",
        cidrAddr.ToPrefixBlock(), block, addr)
    iterator := block.Iterator()
    for next := iterator.Next(); next != nil; next = iterator.Next() {
        fmt.Printf("compare %s with %s: %d\n", next, addr, next.Compare(addr))
    }
}

func incrementAddressToMax(addr, cidrAddr *ipaddr.IPAddress) {
    block := cidrAddr.ToPrefixBlock()
    max := block.GetUpper()
    fmt.Printf("\nstarting with block %s and address %s,\n"+
        "incrementing to block max %s\n", block, addr, max)
    for ; addr.Compare(max) <= 0; addr = addr.Increment(1) {
        fmt.Println(addr)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
starting with block 62.76.47.0/28, equivalent to 62.76.47.0-15,
and address 62.76.47.9
compare 62.76.47.1 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.2 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.3 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.4 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.5 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.6 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.7 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.8 with 62.76.47.9: -1
compare 62.76.47.9 with 62.76.47.9: 0
compare 62.76.47.10 with 62.76.47.9: 1
compare 62.76.47.11 with 62.76.47.9: 1
compare 62.76.47.12 with 62.76.47.9: 1
compare 62.76.47.13 with 62.76.47.9: 1
compare 62.76.47.14 with 62.76.47.9: 1
compare 62.76.47.15 with 62.76.47.9: 1

starting with block 62.76.47.0/28 and address 62.76.47.9,
incrementing to block max 62.76.47.15/28
62.76.47.9
62.76.47.10
62.76.47.11
62.76.47.12
62.76.47.13
62.76.47.14
62.76.47.15
```

Both methods are probably equally efficient with small subnets, but as subnets get large you want to avoid the first solution of incrementing through the entire subnet.  If desired, use the `GetNetIp` method of `ipaddr.IPAddress` to switch over to `net.IP`.